# How can I check if a first/last element has a specific class?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a tab navigation and run into troubles with that.
I would like to disable the previous button if the active tab is the first, and disable the next button if the last tab is active.

How can I check if the first/last tab is active here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  })

  $('#previous').click(function() {
    if($('ul.tabs li.current').prev().length != 0 ){
    $('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current').click();
}
  })

  $('#next').click(function() {
 if($('ul.tabs li.current').next().length != 0 ){
    $('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current').next().addClass('current').click();
  }
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
  line-height: 1.6
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.tabs li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #222;
}

ul.arrownavigation {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.arrownavigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.arrownavigation li:active {
  background: #444;
}

ul.arrownavigation li.disabled {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <ul class="arrownavigation">
    <li id="previous">Previous</li>
    <li id="next">Next</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
    Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Comment: can use `is('ul.tabs li:last)` or `:first`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to check if first and last tab have the `current` class. Slightly modified script (more universal, re-usable) below:

```js
$('.tabs-container').each(function(i) {

    var tabsContainer = $(this);
    var tabsNavigation = tabsContainer.find('.arrownavigation');
    var tabsLinks = tabsContainer.find('.tab-link');
    var tabLinkFirst = tabsContainer.find('.tab-link:first-child');
    var tabLinkLast = tabsContainer.find('.tab-link:last-child');
    var tabsContent = tabsContainer.find('.tab-content');
    var tabsPrevious = tabsContainer.find('.tab-previous');
    var tabsNext = tabsContainer.find('.tab-next');
    
    /* This is the function you need: */
    function checkArrows() {
     tabsPrevious.toggleClass('tab-disabled', tabLinkFirst.hasClass('current'));
        tabsNext.toggleClass('tab-disabled', tabLinkLast.hasClass('current'));
    };
    checkArrows();

    tabsLinks.click(function() {
        var tabSelector = $(this).data('tab');
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $(tabSelector).addClass('current');
        checkArrows();
    });

    tabsPrevious.click(function() {
        var currentTab = tabsContainer.find('.tabs li.current');
        if (currentTab.prev().length > 0) {
            currentTab.removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current').trigger('click');
        }
    });

    tabsNext.click(function() {
        var currentTab = tabsContainer.find('.tabs li.current');
        if (currentTab.next().length > 0) {
            currentTab.removeClass('current').next().addClass('current').trigger('click');
        }
    });

})
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
    line-height: 1.6
}

.tabs-container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.tabs {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.tabs li {
    background: none;
    color: #222;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current {
    background: #ededed;
    color: #222;
}

ul.arrownavigation {
    list-style: none;
}

ul.arrownavigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #111;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.arrownavigation li:active {
    background: #444;
}

ul.arrownavigation li.disabled {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.tab-content {
    display: none;
    background: #ededed;
    padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
    display: inherit;
}

ul.arrownavigation li.tab-disabled {
    background: none #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-container">

    <ul class="arrownavigation">
        <li class="tab-arrow tab-previous">Previous</li>
        <li class="tab-arrow tab-next">Next</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab=".tab-1">Tab One</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab=".tab-2">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab=".tab-3">Tab Three</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab=".tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content tab-1 current">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content tab-2">
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content tab-3">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content tab-4">
        Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>

</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmcfbooe/).

Answer (score 1):

you can change your click function like this

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    var index = $(".tabs li").index(this);

    if (index == 0) 
    {
      $('#previous').hide();
    } 
    else if (index + 1 == $(".tabs li").length) 
    {
      $('#next').hide();
    } 
    else 
    {
      $('#next').show();
      $('#previous').show();
    }

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
})
```